# PayPal API Direct Payment process

Tags: php, paypal

I used usual seller account on sandbox, not wpp.
Can i use direct payments from credit card on that account or i need create only wpp account?
Now i recieve error:

```
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must set up a Website Payments Pro account in order to test the DoDirectPayment API.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to setup buyer account in sandbox and use that one for testing

Comment: I don't need buyer account in sandbox, i just want pay from credit cart to my seller account.